# WP ecommerce - transaction was not accepted

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting message;

Sorry your transaction was not accepted.
Click here to go back to checkout page.

I'm using SagePay and I can replicate the error - It's basically if you wait ages on the SagePay end then process payment - and the SessionID is missing.

Can anybody please help?

Regards

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this end:

http://keyzo.co.uk/blog/wordpress-wp-ecommerce-and-sagepay/

Hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the sessionid is lost payment return timeout to the store or the php session is lost

this can be fixed (any payment method)

at /wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/WPSC-theme/functions/WPSC-transaction_results_functions.php
on line 96 should be more or less like

```
    .....

if(!$dont_show_transaction_results ) {
       if(empty($sessionid) && isset($_GET['pszPurchorderNum']) && $_GET['pszPurchorderNum']!=null) {
         $sessionid=$_GET['pszPurchorderNum'];
       }

       if ( !empty($sessionid) ) { ...
```